# Please help me to write this query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this table :

```
 dt           qnt 
----------   -------
1               10
2               -2
3               -4
4                3
5               -1
6                5
```

How do I create a query to get  this result? (res is a running total column):

```
 dt       qnt       res
----     -----     -----
1         10         10
2         -2          8
3         -4          4
4          3          7
5         -1          6
6          5          11
```

Comment: Explain more... what is it?

Comment: Can you **explain in plain English** what you're trying to do/achieve here??? Don't just dump two table outputs on us and let us figure out what you're trying to do!!

Comment: Add another column and insert values ;)

Comment: what wersion sql server

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using a simple subquery that calculates the sum up to the current row, which should work well on any version of SQL Server;

```
SELECT dt, qnt, 
  (SELECT SUM(qnt) FROM Table1 ts WHERE ts.dt <= t1.dt) res
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER BY dt;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b7c4/1).

If you're using SQL Server 2012, see [Amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756013/477878) for a more efficient query.

Answer (score 2):

If you are Using sql Server 2012 than you can try like this.

```
Select * ,Sum([qnt]) Over(order by dt) from table1
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2341f/1)

Answer (score 2):

Use one of this way :

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1]
        (
          [dt] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                     NOT NULL ,
          qnt  [int] NULL ,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_T1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [dt] ASC )
            WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                   IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
        )
    ON  [PRIMARY]
    GO

    INSERT  INTO dbo.T1 ( qnt ) VALUES  ( 10 )
    INSERT  INTO dbo.T1 ( qnt ) VALUES  ( -2 )
    INSERT  INTO dbo.T1 ( qnt ) VALUES  ( -4 )
    INSERT  INTO dbo.T1 ( qnt ) VALUES  ( 3 )
    INSERT  INTO dbo.T1 ( qnt ) VALUES  ( -1 )
    INSERT  INTO dbo.T1 ( qnt ) VALUES  ( 5 )
    GO

    SELECT  * ,
            RunningSum = T1.qnt + COALESCE(( SELECT   SUM(qnt)
                                               FROM     T1 AS T1Sub
                                               WHERE    ( T1Sub.dt < T1.dt )
                                             ), 0)
    FROM    T1

    Go

    SELECT  T1.dt ,
            T1.qnt ,
            SUM(T1Inner.qnt)
    FROM    T1
            INNER JOIN T1 AS T1Inner ON ( T1.dt >= T1Inner.dt )
    GROUP BY T1.dt ,
            T1.qnt
    ORDER BY T1.dt ,
            T1.qnt

    GO

    SELECT  T1.* ,
            T2.RunningSum
    FROM    T1
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    SUM(qnt) AS RunningSum
                          FROM      T1 AS CAT1
                          WHERE     ( CAT1.dt <= T1.dt )
                        ) AS T2

    Go

    SELECT  * ,
            RunningSum = ( SELECT   SUM(qnt)
                           FROM     T1 AS T1In
                           WHERE    ( T1In.dt <= T1.dt )
                         )
    FROM    T1  

    Go


    -- In Sql Server 2012
    SELECT  * ,
            SUM(T1.qnt) OVER ( ORDER BY T1.dt 
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
                               AS RunningTotal
    FROM    T1



    Drop Table [dbo].[T1]
```